# Carbon milliseconds timestamp using UNIX time

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I'm working with an API that need the time with this format: `"currentTime": 1534431933321` - unit is in MS.

How can I create that in Laravel using carbon?

And how to set my host time with getting that from endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "UNIX Time", can accomplish this with Carbon:

```
//$nowInMs: returns 1534431933321
$nowInMs = now()->getTimeStampMs();  

//$letsParseValue: returns 1674799200000
$letsParseValue = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2023-01-27 10:00:00')->getTimeStampMs();
```

For reference on other getters use: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters

To verify the times use this website: https://currentmillis.com/

Comment: By definition, [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is in seconds, not milliseconds.